# How to replace DataContractSerializer to Protobuf-net serializer in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.ios, protobuf-net

I have WCF service which uses protobuf-net as serializer and Xamarin.iOS app which must consume this service.

I've created precompiled serializer for my DTO classes, but I can't understand how to replace DataContractSerializer in monotouch (Xamarin.iOS) client app, because ProtoBehaviorExtension is inherited from BehaviorExtensionElement, which is unavaliable in ServiceModel 2.

@MarkDaniel in his answer [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24207667/3025040):

> However if you go and get the full System.ServiceModel from the Mono repository on GitHub and build it against the full Protobuf source then you can get it to work; I have done so.

Can anyone tell more about how to extract full System.ServiceModel from Mono and build it with Protobuf?

May be there is another way to serialize/deserialize data in wcf client?

Comment: Another option, of course, is to use a *regular* endpoint (perhaps adding a second one somewhere), that just passes the data as `byte[]` or `Stream`, and worry about serialization / deserialization separately. Not as pretty, but it should work.

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks for advice, it really works. But in this case we use both serializers. For me is important to exclude DataContractSerializer from client.